# How to make tied knots in Blender?

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves

I don't know how to make tied knots, for example when I want to make shoe lace.
Someone can help me, please?
Thank you (:

Comment: using a curve with bevel and taper object, and... be patient !

Comment: Someone may have a better idea... or some trick to do quickly a 'real knot'... or the *torus knot* addon may help too (have a try). There is two version of this addon *torus knot* and *torus knot plus*

Comment: Yeah! I'm going to get this addon right now, big thanks!! :D

Comment: ... found a quicker way... I write an answer in a minute...

Comment: okay! I didn't find the "torus knot" addon more! :/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can start with a simple mesh which roughly defines the knot shape, which for now is flat. Top view here:

[image: top view]

Then give it some relief and add a subsurf modifier, still roughly :

[image]

Now, convert it to a curve :

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then *curve from mesh*
- Enter edit mode, set the curve type to *bezier* then the handles to *auto*
- Now set some bevel to the curve

[image]

Doing this, you may have some adjustments to do, but initial vertices (in "mesh mode") are much more easy to manipulate than starting with a curve from the beginning :

[image]

Comment: Wooow! You've made it, I feel much better, you save me!!!

Comment: How would I use this method to make a moebius loop?

Comment: @Leonardo-Paradox, I don't know if this method is appropriated for a moebius loop. You should ask another question, this is the principle in BSE (as the comments are not intended to be used like in a forum). If you do, be sure to add some pictures or drawings about the final result you want. In this new question you can refer/link to this one if you think it is needed.

Comment: @Leonardo-Paradox, but for now I see no way to do it with this method (curve twisting problem).